# Change permission from -rwxrwxr-x to drwxrwxr-x

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have a php file which is trying to read and write xml files on my Ubuntu server, however the problem is that it does not have permission to do this (permission denied error).

I have tried the following `chown www-data read_write.php` with no luck

What is the proper way to change permission for this file?

**more info**

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 14092 Sep  6 12:33 read_write.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script must be allowed to write in the *directory* in which it tries to create the files. So for example, if the script tries to write a file into the directory `/var/srv/www/script_output/`, do

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/srv/www/script_output/
chmod 771 /var/srv/www/script_output
```

Make sure that you do not give permissions for writing in the directory that the script resides in (otherwise, an attacker hijacking the script would be able to overwrite the script itself). Also, files in that directory should not be permitted to be run (as PHP or whatever).

By the way, the `d` in `drwxrwxr-x` only means that the given node is a directory.